# What are the Android application lifecycle methods? (not activity life cycle methods.)

Tags: android

In my android application, there are 10 activities. I identify all these activities by the number. lets say activity 1 to activity 10.

1. Activity 1 is splash screen.
2. Activity 2 = login screen
3. Activity 3 to 10 are normal pages of book.

Now when I first login to my app, it shows me splash screen and then login screen. My app asks about password. Then it redirects me to activity 3 which is page 1 of book. Now lets assume I am on page 5 i.e. activity 7 and I suddenly pressed Home button, then application goes to background state.

**Now what I want is that when I again open my application and my app in foreground, it will not start activity 7. I want to start activity 2 (login screen) first, then It ask for a correct password. If the user enters the correct password then only activity 7 starts.
So basically my question is that is there any way to Identify whether my application will enter to background or did enter in foreground before starting activity? (i.e. android application life cycle methods.) So that I can launch login activity first through that app life cycle method. This is possible for me in iOS through, app delegate life cycle methods. But how I can do it with android?**

Comment: How are you remembering last active activity in iOS ?

Comment: I am going to save its activity number to shared preferences

Comment: Use the same concept here. And once the user logs in, transfer him/her to the respective Activity through the use of Intents.

Comment: @varun - sure. But from where I can transfer. when I start app again in android, my last activity automatically launches

Comment: @Sanket : I'm answering your comment in the answers section below. Please have a look.

Comment: @varun - ok. Thanks

Comment: @Sanket : Answer posted. Please do have a look. If you still have any problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: Let me how you are passing from one activity to another . Please provide some code

Comment: @aditi - I am using "startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, TargetActivityName.class))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the Activity LifeCycle. When you close your app by pressing the home button, the onStop() method of the respective Activity which was active at the time is called upon. This method does not destroy the Activity completely, it only  stops it.

The Activities in the Android OS are destroyed by calling onDestroy() method of the respective Activity. However, onDestroy() method cannot be called directly because it is a method of Activity's LifeCycle. It gets called automatically by the Android OS. To ensure that Activity's onDestroy() method gets called as soon as your Activity stops, we will call finish() method inside the onStop() method of your respective Activity(s).

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

Now, when you'll start your app again, it will start from the beginning i.e. the splash screen.

Comment: hey thanks :)

I think this is the case for which I am searching. Seems to be great for me. I got what you are saying. I am gonna try this now. If any difficulty found, I will get back to you. Thanks again

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please accept my answer.

Comment: Yeah sure. Its working with your logic. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want to give any headroom to the user and want to log her off as soon as the app goes into background, we can use the general activity life cycle to differentiate when the app when to background and when a screen switch occurred. Your Application class can look like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    public boolean userLoggedoff;

    ... 

    @Override  
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());

        if (userLoggedoff) 
             startPasswordActivity() // Make sure you add 'CLEAR_TOP' flag to intent
    }

    ... 

}
```

Make your 'logged in' activities according to following template:

```
public class Act1 extends Activity {

    private boolean legitSwitch;

    ...

    // Legit app switch
    private void startNewAct() {
         legitSwitch = true;
         ...
         startActivity()
    }


    protected void onPause() {
         if (!legitSwitch)
              ((MyApplication) getApplication()).userLoggedOff = true;
    }

}
```

Make sure you set the `userLoggedOff` boolean to true from your login activity. Hope this helps. Now remember that after pressing the home button and returning, the above method will still show the previous activity for an instant since we are doing stuff on `onActivityResumed()` method of the application class but will immediately also start the Login Activity because how dare the user press the home button!

Comment: Thanks. Got your point. I am gonna try this also in my project. It was great learning from you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Application class for this purpose. You need to implement Activity lifecycle callbacks there like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private boolean userLoggedOff;
    private Handler mHandler;

    ...

    @Override 
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());

        if (userLoggedoff)
             startPasswordActivity()
        else {
             mHandler.cancelCallbacksAndMessages(null);
             userLoggedOff = false;
        }
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Paused", activity.getLocalClassName());

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  userLoggedOff = true;
             }
        }, 5000);
    } 

    ...

}
```

Now, here what we are trying to is that as soon as `onPause()` of any activity is called we trigger a delayed event using handler to logging the user off. This event can be cancelled only when `onResume()` of any activity is called within 5 seconds (like you know, this may be called during regular activity switching or also when the app comes from the background but).

This might solve your issue elegantly, I guess.

Comment: thanks shaishav. Very helpfull post I think. But suppose I pressed home button by mistake and  immediately lauches app within 5 seconds, then also I think same activity will start... Thats the case where I also want to start my login activity again

Comment: So, you don't want to give any head room to the user? One click on the Home button and 'hasta la vista baby' ? :)

Comment: @Sanket posted another ans, try that